# How to get position and size of other apps with electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Like [Loom](https://www.loom.com/), I want to get window position and window size of other apps to show recording area.
I can get only size of a window with this code.

```
const constraints = {...}
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
const {height, width} = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings()
```

but I couldn't figure out how to get position of specific window on desktop...

With BrowserWindow.getAllWindows() and webContents.getAllWebContents(), it seems that I can get position and size of window only created by electron.
How can I get them of windows of other apps?

Comment: I believe you might find the information you need in [Electron's documentation on `desktopCapturer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer) which will let you "capture", i.e. record, the user's desktop.

Comment: thank you for commenting!
yes I did. With desktopCaputurerer, I can record specific window and get some informatiion of it, but it seems there is no position information in [DesktopCaptureSource Object](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/desktop-capturer-source).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I also want to find out what is visible on a given screen and at what co-ordinates or positions